# Which pre-ANSI C compilers allowed a conditional expression as Lvalue?

Tags: history, c, identify-this-software

Soon after learning the C language in the late 80s, before an ANSI C compiler was available on the machines I was using, it occurred to me to check if the following compiles

```
int a, b, c;
foo() {
    (a == 0 ? b : c) = 1;
}
```

and it did! The compiler has propagated the Lvalue property of the last two operands of the ternary expression to the expression itself. For a while, I amused people by demonstrating them that "Easter egg" in the compiler.

Now, of course, according to the ANSI C standard, we have to write `*(a == 0 ? &b : &c)`.

However, I cannot remember or figure out which compiler it was. The original K&R compiler I tried on an online PDP-11 simulator says "3: Lvalue required", as well as a compiler used in BSD 2.9 (PCC-based, I guess?).

It could have been a compiler on MS-DOS, but I remember that at least one compiler on a UNIX platform also allowed that.

I'm not trying to find out exactly which one it was in my case, or which one was the earliest; an example of a pre-ANSI C compiler written in the 70-80s for any commercially-available platform/OS which existed at the time and which compiles the above test case would be enough.

Googling "lvalue ternary expression" yields discussions about the fact that a ternary expression can be an Lvalue in C++ but not in the contemporary C.

Comment: Which machine were you using?

Comment: @OmarL Which machine*s*, rather.  IBM PC clones, mostly. Also there was at least one obscure UNIX-like workstation with a non-x86 CPU (not by Sun).

Comment: Pet gripe: it's the *conditional operator* in a *conditional expression*. Calling it "the operator with three operands" is just silly.

Comment: As to the question - I too recall it as possible somewhere. My possibilities would be VAX C (on VMS) - the pre-ANSI compiler written by Cutler, not DEC C (on VMS) = and whatever was on Ultrix 32.

Comment: @another-dave Thank you; is there a way to confirm that?

Comment: Other than poking around looking for running systems, probably not. Maybe there are manuals that are explicit about it.  On a quick look, I came up empty.

Comment: Looks like internal code reuse in the compiler.

Comment: I wonder if it would accept something where not all possible evaluations are lvalues? Something like `(a == 0 ? b : 0)`

Comment: @OmarL Why would it? `0` is not an lvalue, therefore the whole expression isn't.

Comment: It has to be possible to 'balance' (as we used to say in Algol-68 circles) the expression to a single type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first gnu C compilers predate the ANSI C Standard, and unless invoked with the `-pedantic` flag would ease many restrictions which the authors viewed as, well pedantic.  I don't remember for certain if the ability to treat ternary expressions as lvalues was among them, but I think it was, along with the ability to treat certain cast expressions as lvalues in cases where the operands were likewise.  I think the guiding philosophy was that if there was only one thing a construct could sensibly mean, and the construct might be useful, it should have that meaning.  Very different from the philosophy of gcc's maintainers today.

Comment: IIRC, my experience of this construct being allowed by a compiler predates my acquaintance with GCC, so if you're right, GCC was likely not the only one or the first one.

Comment: GCC 1.21, circa 1988, indeed documents such an extension.  GCC 0.9 is the next earlier version that seems to be readily available; it doesn't document any extensions, but it's not so easy to build it to test whether it supports this.

Comment: SunOS 3.4 (1986) C compiler allows casts on the left-hand side. `(int)status = RPC_INTR;` will compile. The approximate predecessor of SunOS, 4.2BSD, C compiler didn't allow that. This could be a clue to the origin of LHS casts.